# Python: Find matching records in two lists of dictionaries (different key names)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got two lists of dictionaries with different keys but overlapping values, something like this:

```
list_a = [{key1: value_a, key2: value_b}, {key1: value_c, key2: value_d}, ...]
list_b = [{key3: value_a, key4: value_z}, {key3: value_c, key4: value_z}, ...]
```

I want to join them together so that I can append `key4` to the `list_a` or indicate that there isn't a matching record found.

I've been using a nested `for` loop to do this like:

```
for i in list_a:
    for v in list_b:
        if i["key1"] == v["key3"]:
            i["key4"] = v["key4"]
        else:
            i["key4"] = False
```

This doesn't seem very programmatically efficient since I have to loop through all of `list_b` for every `list_a` value. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

The actual data I'm working with is more complex so I've got a few conditions to match on in each list.

I looked at list comprehensions, but wasn't sure which way to go with this.

Any pointers (for this novice!) are appreciated!

Edit: Expected output:

```
list_a = [{key1: value_a, key2: value_b, key4: value_z},
          {key1: value_c, key2: value_d, key4: value_z},
          {key1: value_e, key2: value_f, key4: False}, ...]
```

Basically find matching entries in `list_b` to `list_a` based on values, then update `list_a` with other k-v pairs from the matches or indicate a match wasn't found.

Comment: Can you include the expected output too in the question?

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav Done! Sorry, should've included that initially.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `list_b` to a `dict` for easy look-up

**Ex:**

```
list_a = [{key1: value_a, key2: value_b}, {key1: value_c, key2: value_d}, ...]
list_b = [{key3: value_a, key4: value_z}, {key3: value_c, key4: value_z}, ...]

list_b_l = {i['key3']: i['key4'] for i in list_b}

for i in list_a:
    i['key4'] = list_b_l.get(i['key1'], False)
```